# Is that possible to import css file as string in es6?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, es6-modules

I want to pack the css file and insert it into shadow DOM in my app.

I have tried the way from [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#tostring):

As following the file :**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')


module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: {
      content: './content/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
              test: /\.vue$/,
              loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
              test: /\.css$/,
              use: [
                'vue-style-loader',
                'to-string-loader',
                {
                  loader: 'css-loader',
                  options: {}
                }
              ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried to use the way like this:

```
const css = require('./test.css').toString();

console.log(css); // [Object, Object]

import styles from './test.css';
console.log(styles) // {}
```

**CSS file:**

```
#app{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  width: 420px;
  height: 420px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

It seem not to work for me.

Is there having a way to do it?

Comment: @DacreDenny nope, it's a solution from `css-loader`

Comment: I tried `const css = require('to-string-loader!css-loader!./test.css').toString();` and `const css = require('to-string-loader!./test.css').toString();`, the first way is CssSyntaxError, another output the same result.

Comment: Output is `"[object Object]"`

Comment: Can you include the contents of your css in the OP?

Comment: I have added the css file context in the OP

Comment: Is that should be implemented by `style loader`?

Comment: should not be nessisary, but might be worth a try

Comment: At the render page, the `<style></style>` has been inserted in head element

Comment: Can you include your full webpack config

Comment: Maybe that is a to grab the style tag to insert it into `Shadow DOM`

Comment: @DacreDenny I have added it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your `webpack.config.js`, it seems that the order you've specifeid the loaders for `.css` files is back to front.

Try revervsing the order of loaders in the `use` array so that the results of the `css-loader` are passed to the `to-string-loader`, and then from the `to-string-loader` to your script:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        'to-string-loader',
        'css-loader'
    ]
}
```

Also, I'm not sure you need to include `vue-style-loader` here, which is why I've removed that from the loaders applied to css files.

Comment: The order is same as origin, `to-string-loader` is an index lower than `css-loader`

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. If you want to insert the css file into the Shadow DOM, and the `vue-style-loader` is useless

Comment: I remove the `vue-style-loader`, and it works for me. Thanks a lot!